# Is it good practice to require my Laravel 4 package to be "extended" by the user in order to use it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, package, extends

There are 2 approaches I can think of to creating a Laravel 4 package that accomplishes my goals:

**Require users of the package to extend it:**

```
// YourCoolService.php

class YourCoolService extends MyCoolPackage {

      // add the appropiate properties & methods 
      // that MyCoolPackage will expect to use

}
```

```
// YourCoolController.php

      ...

      // Example of how it would be called
      $output = YourCoolService::make()->withInput(Input::all())->render();

      ...
```

**Or pass the class name as a string argument into my package:**

```
// YourCoolService.php

class YourCoolService {   // <-- no extending here

      // add the appropiate properties & methods 
      // that MyCoolPackage will expect to use

}
```

```
// YourCoolController.php

      ...

      // The passed class name would be used to instantiate the class
      // by MyCoolPackage so that the package can use the expected 
      // properties and methods in the class
      $output = MyCoolPackage::make('Namespace\YourCoolService')->withInput(Input::all())->render();

      ...
```

"Extend" solution
PRO's

- The call from the Controller is leaner
- I don't have to use the Namespace directly on the call in the Controller.
- I can create abstract methods to inform the user they need to implement them (although this can be done with an Interface as well).

CON's

- Users can't extend any other class because they are extending MyCoolPackage
- If I wanted to have some "helper" functions in MyCoolPackage, then calls like `parent::helper();` would appear throughout the YourCoolService class (but I suppose I could still call it like `MyCoolPackage::helper();` as well).

"Pass Class Name" solution
PRO's

- User's don't have to extend anything
- It's apparent from the call in the Controller what package is being used
- If I wanted to have some "helper" functions in MyCoolPackage, then I could call them like `MyCoolPackage::helper('foo');` anywhere in YourCoolService class and it would be obvious where they are coming from.

CON's

- The call in the controller is longer
- I might need to create an Interface for MyCoolPackage to be used by YourCoolService (although I don't think this is absolutely necessary)
- The call in the controller needs the full namespace in the passed string (**is there a way to avoid having to include the namespace in the string?**)

**What's the best practice on creating a package that requires properties and methods to exist in the user's own class implementation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that it is better to go with [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), and given the DI features that Laravel provides you can allow users of your package to instead inject a reference to an instance of `MyCoolPackage` in an object's constructor. Your `make` method then would not have to be called statically (or through a facade, if that's the case).

Basically the idea is that, whenever a user of your package is creating a new service, that service class should have an instance to your package injected into it.

```
<?php namespace Namespace;

use MyCoolPackage\MyCoolPackage;

class YourCoolService {

    protected $myCoolPackage;

    public function __construct( MyCoolPackage $package )
    {
        $this->myCoolPackage = $package;
    }

    ...

$this->myCoolPackage->make('Namespace\YourCoolController')
    ->withInput(Input::all())->render();
```

Or better yet:

```
$this->myCoolPackage->make($this)->withInput(Input::all())->render();
```

To provide for the DI functionality, you would need to create a Service provider to bind an instance of `MyCoolPackage` in the IoC whenever `MyCoolPackage\MyCoolPackage` is type hinted in a constructor. See: http://laravel.com/docs/packages#service-providers.

Since you're leaving `YourCoolService` to be defined elsewhere by someone else, there's not much else you can do than provide some sort of paradigm for the people who will be writing the services to follow.  If you can provide them an interface to implement, that would be the best case as it would provide people writing these services a template to start from.

You can also provide an abstract base class that will give users a default implementation for any optional methods that all other implementations can choose to either override or not.  This approach would be similar to your 'extends' method and offer you some of the same pro's.

I've never been a huge fan of passing class names as strings. I bet there are some use cases for it, but to me its just making an implicit depedency where you don't really need one.

Comment: Can you expand in your answer on how you would call it from a Controller?

Comment: Call like this: `$output = YourCoolService::myCoolPackage::make()->withInput(Input::all())->render();` ???

Comment: No. If you really want to make it a static method on the client service, you're going to have to go about it differently but I would not suggest it.

Comment: So say I don't use it "statically", how would you call it from the Controller?

Comment: This line `$this->myCoolPackage->make('Namespace\YourCoolController')
    ->withInput(Input::all())->render();` doesn't make sense to me? You are calling the Controller from your Service? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo `Namespace\YourCoolController` should be `Namespace\YourCoolService`...fixed.

Comment: But still I need clarity on what your call would be. `$this->myCoolPackage->make('Namespace\YourCoolService')->withInput(Input::all()->render());` still doesn't make sense inside a Controller?

Comment: Ok I think I might know what your solution is trying to do...A user could put this in the constructor `$this->myCoolPackageObj = $package->make($this);` and then in the Controller `$output = YourCoolService::myCoolPackageObj->withInput(Input::all())->render();`

Comment: @David Graham almost.. if you try to access the myCoolPackageObj statically like that, though, you're going to get a syntax error.  You would need a reference to an instance of `YourCoolService`.  In a controller, you can inject an instance of that, however, in exactly the same manner (or users of your package could)

Comment: Even better, if the myCoolPackageObj was named `make` or `create` so it would read in the controller: `$output = YourCoolService::make->withInput(Input::all())->render();`

Comment: Sure, that could work.  I would still caution you against making static calls like that (if indeed it is static and not through a facade)

Comment: The package is using a facade. However the property in the Service would be declared static so I could do the one liner `YourCoolService::make->...`

Comment: How would you do the one-liner in the Controller? We are almost there!

Comment: In the controller, you would need to `use YourCoolService\YourCoolService` (or whatever the namespace/classname is).  Since it's a facade then that should be all that you need to do: `YourCoolService::make....`

Comment: OH I see what you are saying...my constructor would throw an error for setting a value on a static property using `$this` ?

Comment: No, since it's a facade my concerns are no longer valid.  If it truly was a static method call, then saying: `YourCoolService::make(..)` (and you use `$this` in the make method) would throw the error: PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context

Comment: Only the package has a facade. Not the Service. Am I still in trouble then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44251/discussion-between-watcher-and-david-graham)

Comment: Update your answer (based on the assumption that MyCoolPackage is a facade....but NOT YourCoolService) to reflect what we are talking about here, so I can give you credit.

Comment: I think your solution combines the PRO of a cleaner one-liner, and the freedom of not having to extend anything. Great!! Waiting for your update then I can accept! Thanks for the great chat!

Comment: oh, BTW, I think using a static method called "make()" to do what the constructor is doing would be the better approach then a static property I think. `public static function make(MyCoolPackage $package)` and then inside it `return $package->make($this);` which allows me in the Controller to do `$output = YourCoolService->make()->withInput(Input::all())->render();` which is PERFECT!!

Comment: See my answer that complements yours...what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from watcher, I ended up doing something like this:

```
// YourCoolService.php

class YourCoolService implements MyCoolPackageInterface {

    public function makeCool(MyCoolPackage $myCoolPackage)
    {
        return $myCoolPackage->make($this);
    }

}


// YourController.php

$output = (new YourService)->makeCool()->withInput(Input::all())->render(); 

...
```

Has advantage of nice looking call in Controller and is free from inheritance. Great!

Comment: You are not using `static` there. Replace with `self` re-run your tests and you'll see that your application behaves exactly the same. This has nothing to do with late static binding (if you're not using class-aliasing in the controller script).

Comment: I just wanted to use `static` in case this class ends up being extended later. YourCoolService is provided by the users of the package...they may decide to create a BaseCoolService or something and extend it from YourCoolService. Then `self` would not be correct anymore?

Comment: I did not check to see if the `$instance` already exists, like I see in many singleton implementations. Why would I need to do that?